# Consensus tree or "bootstrap proportions" from multiple hclust objects

Tags: r, dendrogram, hclust

I have a list of hclust objects resulting from slight variations in one variable (for calculating the distance matrix)

- now I would like to make a consensus tree from this list.

Is there a generic package to do this? I am hacking my way through
some code from maanova and it seems to work - but it's ugly and it
needs a lot of hacking since I am not doing "normal" bootstrapping (it's
chemical data).

/Palle Villesen, Denmark

```
c1_list <- seq(10,100,by=10)
c2 <- 30
e<- 1
mboot <- list()
for (i in 1: length(c1_list) ) {
   c1 <- c1_list[i]
   cat("Doing C1=",c1,"...")
   x <- hclust(custom_euclidean(t(log2(data[, all]+1)), c1,c2,e), method='average')
   cat("..done\n")
   mboot[[i]] <- x # To get hclust object back use mbot[[i]] to get i'th object
}

#### Now extract the robust groups from mboot...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, have a look at [Allan Tucker's code for consensus clustering](http://people.brunel.ac.uk/~cssrajt/RConsensus/), related to his paper ["Consensus Clustering and Functional Interpretation of Gene Expression Data"](http://people.brunel.ac.uk/~cssrajt/Papers/GBConsensus.pdf).

Here are a few other pointers:

- You mentioned that you're using [the maanova package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maanova/); this can build a consensus tree out of bootstrap cluster result with the `consensus()` function.  Have you tried that?
- The [ape package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ape/) is intended for phylogenetic tree analysis, so it's possibly not completely relevant, but you might look into it.  There is [an example using hclust on R-Help](http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@stat.math.ethz.ch/msg55545.html).
- Similarly, the [nem package, which is part of bioconductor](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.4/bioc/html/nem.html) has some examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that sounds like what I'm looking for. And yes - I saw the consensus() function, but I needed to create the correct object of multiple hclust objects (+ some extra stuff)...

Also it creates a condensed dendrogram, where I want "bootstrap" proportions...

So that was why I was looking for a simpler function that simply compares n hclust objects and creates some kind of consensus...

Answer (score 0):

Hm, that sounds like a boosting approach applied to clustering, and a quick Google search reveals quite an existing literature on [boosting clustering](http://www.google.com/search?q=boosting+clustering). Maybe that is a start?

As for R code, there are always the Task Views on [Clustering](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Cluster.html) and [Machine Learning](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MachineLearning.html).